# Why can't I use Cauchy-Schwarz to show convergence of the Fourier series in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Recently I read that there are $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ functions such that their Fourier series does not converge in the norm of $L^1$, that is if $S_N(f)(x)$ represents the $N$-nth partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$, there exists $f$ such that:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |S_N(f)(x)-f(x)| dx $$

does not approaches $0$ as $N$ approaches infinity.
However, it is widely known that:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |S_N(f)(x)-f(x)|^2 dx \rightarrow0 $$

as $N\rightarrow\infty$. Why can´t I use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, that states if two functions $F,G$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$:

$$\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F(x) \overline{G(x)} dx\right|^2\leq\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|F(x)|^2dx\right) \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|G(x)|^2dx\right)$$

by taking $F(x)=|S_N(f)(x)-f(x)|$ and $G(x)=1$ so that:

$$\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|S_N(f)(x)-f(x)|1 dx\right|^2\leq\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|S_N(f)(x)-f(x)|^2dx\right) \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}1dx\right) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|S_N(f)(x)-f(x)|^2$$

and then take $N\rightarrow\infty$?

I´m realy struggling to see what hypothesis I´m assuming that should prevent me to do that

Comment: You are only showing that $L^{1}$ convergence holds for $L^{2}$ functions.

Comment: Oh, I see, so if $f$ is in $L^2$ it also holds true in $L^1$. In the case of Riemann integrable functions on $\mathbb{T}$ (so that they are bounded) that would implie botth right?

Comment: Yes, RI functions are bounded so if they are in $L^{1}$ they are also in $L^{2}$.